# Filtered cells not pasting on a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Stuck at this annoying problem, I want to filter cells from a data in M_Sheet, select the filtered region of cells that have "New Code" in Range("x6") and paste it in a new sheet.
For some reasons the cells are not copying or pasting

```
Set M_Sheet = Comp_Book.Worksheets("Sheet1")    'Comp_Book is a variable for a book currently open

M_Sheet.range("B6:F1835").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="New Code"
M_Sheet.range("B6:F1835").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'A code suggestion needed to paste the copied region in new a worksheet 
 starting from Column B
```

What i have tried

```
 Dim N_Sheet = Comp_Book.Worksheets("Sheet2)
 N_Sheet.cells(2,2).paste
```

Comment: Updated it
Tried several ways which resulted in a few mistakes like these

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sure there is help here, but you have to be a little more specific, because there are multiple issues. When assigning a range you have to use the `Set` keyword: `Set Flter = ...`. With `B6` you are qualifying one cell only. You have just opened a new workbook which becomes the `ActiveWorkbook` and is empty, but you are applying an `AutoFilter` to it in the line `Worksheets("Sheet1")...`. What are you trying to accomplish  with `SpecialCells` and `Entirecolumn`? There is an edit button below your post. Use it to do some clarifications.

Comment: yes
Comp_Book is basically the activebook

Comment: There's no need to filter and copy values. You can set the range and assign those values to the new sheet. No copy/paste. Are you trying to create a new sheet with ```N_Sheet```? If you could provide more code, including how you're setting the workbook, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoFilter feat. CurrentRegion and SpecialCells

**The Code**

```
Sub AutoFilterRange()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("Comp.xlsm")
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = src.Range("B6").CurrentRegion
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="New Code"
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets.Add
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    tgt.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' Show all data.
    'src.ShowAllData
    ' Turn off AutoFilter.
    'rng.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code assigns the range in `Comp_Book.Sheet1` and sets a variable to a new worksheet. It will filter the range for "New Code" in `Column G`, and then copy visible cells in the range to the new worksheet. Comments are provided in the code.

```
Sub FilterRangeCopytoNewSheet()
    'Define your copy range and destination worksheet variables
    Dim cpyrng As Range: Set cpyrng = Comp_Book.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:F1835")
    Dim destws As Worksheet: Set destws = Comp_Book.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False 'Clear any filter
            
            cpyrng.AutoFilter 6, "New Code" 'Field 6 will filter on Column G
                
            cpyrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destws.Cells(2, 2) 'Copy visible to new sheet
            
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False 'Clear filter
End Sub
```